# Unable to connect all the machines in the network after connecting to openvpn server

Tags: openvpn

I have connected to openvpn server, but i can access only the server, not all the machines in the network.
I have routed the subnet behind the vpn network in the server config file and did the ip forwarding. My server machine and gateway machines are different.

This is my server config file:

```
dev-node "ServerVPN"
mode server
port 1194

proto tcp4-server
dev tun
tls-server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ta.key" 0
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh2048.pem"
ifconfig 10.0.0.102 10.0.0.101
ifconfig-pool 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.252
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.0.0.102"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config"
verb 3
route-delay 5
route-method exe
```

This my client config file:

```
remote ************* 
port 1194
client

proto tcp4-client
dev tun
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\sagarvpn.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\sagarvpn.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
```